# Spark fails to reconfigure log4j2 when using plug-ins bundled in fat jars

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j2, amazon-emr

After upgrading Spark code base from 3.2 to 3.3+, porting Log4j1 to Log4j2 code, we find that Spark doesn't let us reconfigure Log4j programmatically like we were able to do before.

I use *Maven shade* or *Spring boot* plug-ins to package a fat jar with all required dependencies. Once packaged, there is a Log4j2 plug-in present in the jar, in this case `log4j-layout-template-json`. When using Maven shade, I do add the [Maven Shade Log4j2 Transformer](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.edwgiz/log4j-maven-shade-plugin-extensions).

The code that reconfigures log4j2 is the following:

```scala
val context = LoggerContext.getContext(false)
context.setConfigLocation(new URI(s"classpath:log4j2-console-json.properties"))
```

This file is present in resources and contain the following configuration:

```
appender.consoleJson.type=Console
appender.consoleJson.name=consoleJson
appender.consoleJson.target=SYSTEM_OUT
appender.consoleJson.layout.type=JsonTemplateLayout
appender.consoleJson.layout.eventTemplateUri=classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json
appender.consoleJson.layout.eventTemplateAdditionalField[0].type=EventTemplateAdditionalField
appender.consoleJson.layout.eventTemplateAdditionalField[0].key=foo
appender.consoleJson.layout.eventTemplateAdditionalField[0].value=bar

logger.sample.name=sample
logger.sample.level=info
logger.sample.appenderRefs=consoleJson
logger.sample.appenderRef.consoleJson.ref=consoleJson
logger.sample.additivity=false
```

Then, a simple `main` calls this code and logs some lines.

```
package sample

import org.apache.logging.log4j.{Level, LogManager}
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.{Logger, LoggerContext}

import java.net.URI
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val context = LoggerContext.getContext(false)
    context.setConfigLocation(new URI(s"classpath:log4j2-console-json.properties"))

    val logger = LogManager.getLogger("sample").asInstanceOf[Logger]
    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO)
    println(logger.getAppenders.asScala.keys)

    logger.info("Foo: 42")
    println("Done.")
  }
}
```

When the jar is packaged, I expect to be able to reconfigure log4j programmatically like this. Note that the reason for configuring programmatically is that we have multiple appenders, coming from different plug-ins, that need configurations to be set in the application code.

The problem was boiled down to a simple project that reproduces the issue, which can be found here: https://github.com/jeanfrancisroy/spark-log4j2-issue.

When running the application using `java` directly, Log4j2 is reconfigured correctly, and the appender that uses a plug-in (present in the shaded jar) works as expected:

```
> java -cp target/sample_2.12-1.0.0-shaded.jar sample.Main

Appenders: Set(consoleJson)
{"@version":1,"source_host":"my-host","message":"Foo: 42","thread_name":"main","@timestamp":"2023-09-27T15:10:47.529-0400","level":"INFO","logger_name":"sample","foo":"bar"}
Done.
```

However, when running with `spark-submit`, here is the result:

```
> spark-submit --class sample.Main target/sample_2.12-1.0.0-shaded.jar

2023-09-27 17:19:20,206 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for JsonTemplateLayout
2023-09-27 17:19:20,209 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for EventTemplateAdditionalField
2023-09-27 17:19:20,209 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for JsonTemplateLayout
2023-09-27 17:19:20,209 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender for element Console: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.findNamedNode(PluginElementVisitor.java:104)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.visit(PluginElementVisitor.java:88)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.injectFields(PluginBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:123)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1063)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1055)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:664)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:258)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:304)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:621)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:694)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfigLocation(LoggerContext.java:679)
    at sample.Main$.main(Main.scala:12)
    at sample.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1020)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

2023-09-27 17:19:20,210 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender for element Console: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:260)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1063)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1055)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:664)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:258)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:304)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:621)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:694)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfigLocation(LoggerContext.java:679)
    at sample.Main$.main(Main.scala:12)
    at sample.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1020)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

2023-09-27 17:19:20,211 main ERROR Null object returned for Console in Appenders.
2023-09-27 17:19:20,211 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "consoleJson" for logger config "sample"
Set()
Done.
```

Note that I tried to add the appender programmatically too (see in the example repository), and it won't work either.

The only solution that works so far is to avoid using the log4j2 plug-ins from the shaded jar. We can manually push those jars in the cluster running Spark and force the driver classpath to consider them, like so:

```
> spark-submit --driver-class-path jars/log4j-layout-template-json-2.19.0.jar --class sample.Main target/sample_2.12-1.0.0-shaded.jar
```

However, doing so would require us to change our deployment procedures (not only deploying shaded jars for our Spark applications but also packaging external jars and installing them on the clusters), which is something I'd like to avoid.

Please let me know if you have any trick I didn't try yet.